# How to handle large transactions under Oracle?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

Our application is based on Hibernate 3.5, Spring 3.1 and under Oracle I keep running into Max Cursors Exceeded issues, mainly when dealing with large transactions (large in terms of the number of entities involved, the number of queries executed). No such issues occur when running the application on top of H2, MS SQL Server or MySQL.

If I've understood the results of my investigations correctly, Oracle creates a cursor for every ResultSet built during a transaction, and these cursors are only released upon calling `close` on the `Connection` (i.e the Hibernate Session).

My questions (for now):

1. Is there a way to make Oracle clean up the cursors while the
   transaction is ongoing? There are a great many query results that
   aren't needed after a particular point in the transaction, but
   Oracle appears to keep cursors open.
2. Is there a "normal" max cursor setting? The default is 50, most of
   our customers have something like 400-600 cursors set, but some of
   the forum posts I've seen seem to suggest that a few thousand is
   more common. We also appear to be getting a lot of pushback from our
   client DBAs when we suggest to increase the max cursor count to
   (say) 5000. Is that really such a big deal?

Frankly, most of the forum posts I've read were to do with ResultSet/Statement/Connection leaks, but from our analyses we don't have them; the moment we close the connection, the current cursor count goes back to normal. We seem to be the only ones having issues with trying to perform a few hundred operations in a single transaction. Is that really this abnormal?

Thanks for any advice; this stuff is making even my gray hairs fall out

Comment: we regularly require up to 8000.  not a huge resource drain.

Comment: If setting a large value helps, go for it.  Just make sure that there is no leak(as you are already doing).

Comment: Did you do an experiment with newer versions of Hibernate? 3.5 is -really- old. You might be barking up a very old bug /design flaw which has already been fixed a long time ago. I've done some pretty gnarly stuff with Oracle through Hibernate 3.6, never ran into this problem as an example.

Comment: We have an upgrade to Hibernate 4 on the to do list for the next minor release, so thus far not considered an upgrade to 3.6... but I'm gonna give that a whirl right now. Thanks

Comment: In almost all cases running into an "Max Cursors Exceeded" problem indicates a bug in your code: you are not closing ResultSets and Statements properly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name alas that is not fair to say when there is a magic wand tool such as Hibernate in between which is hiding all the JDBC details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle creates cursor for every resultset and releases it upon closing the resultset (jdbc ResultSet.close() or similar). Default of 50 open cursors per session is enough for any well-designed application (once I measured it, and in production mode it never raised over than 20).

You should check how to make Hibernate to close resultsets after fetching. Generally, I cannot imagine what session should do if it really requires 1000 open cursors. I never saw max_open_cursors more than 1000 set, so, I guess, it's enough for bad-designed applications too (but... there is no limit for perfection in sober fact, and I never use Hibernate).

Every cursor means some memory, so increasing max_open_cursors is not zero-price workaround.

Comment: I've read somewhere (don't ask where, I wish I remembered, but it feels I read every single document with the word Oracle in it on the web) that Oracle only removes the cursors upon calling Connection.close. So, I've gone through the code once more and found one or two more possible leaks, and we're now retesting.

Answer (score 2):

You would say that you have some kind of resource leak. Such an issue is in 99.99% of cases caused by a bug in an application. You should use java7 construct try-with-resources where possible. Usual way how to investigate these issues is:

- request SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE from DBAs (this will give you an access to `v$` Oracle view)
- let out application run while wasting resources
- check our opened cursors via `select * from v$open_cursor;`. If you're lucky you will get Sql query for every leaked cursor.
- if you were NOT using hibernate the sql text would point you straight into point in your source codes. But since you use hibernate you can just guess. Entity manager is quite unpredictable sometimes.

PS: cursor is something like a thread in JVM. It is a place if execution of some code in "some" virtual machine. You can have many cursors on a single connection. Cursor is closed, when you close a result set. By doing this you tell Oracle that you do no more care about any further rows coming from SQL query. Of course, when you close connection, all it's cursors are closed too. But please do not close connection, when you just need close a result set. Opening of the new connection is very exhaustive task.

Comment: Thanks, doing exactly that right now (see also my comment to Sanders the Softwarer's post)