# Can MAX_UTILIZATION for PROCESSES reached cause "Unable to get managed connection" Exception?

Tags: oracle, jboss, connection-pooling

A JBoss 5.2 application server log was filled with thousands of the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for jdbc_TestDB
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:441)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:424)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:496)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:96)
... 9 more 
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] )
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:311)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:689)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:404)
... 13 more
```

I've stripped off the first part of the exception, which is basically our internal JDBC wrapper code which tries to get a DB connection from the pool.

Looking at the Oracle DB side I ran the query:

```
select resource_name, current_utilization, max_utilization, limit_value 
from v$resource_limit 
where resource_name in ('sessions', 'processes');
```

This produced the output:

```
RESOURCE_NAME   CURRENT_UTILIZATION     MAX_UTILIZATION     LIMIT_VALUE
processes       1387                    1500                1500
sessions        1434                    1586                2272
```

Given the fact that that PROCESSES limit of 1500 was reached, would this cause the JBoss exceptions we experienced? I've also been investigating the possibility of connection leaks, but haven't found any evidence of that so far.

What is the recommended course of action here? Is simply increasing the limit a valid solution?

Answer (score 0):

hmm strange. is it possible, that exception wrapping in JBOSS hides the original error? You should get some sql exception whose text starts with `ORA-`. Maybe your JDBC wrapper does not handle errors properly.

The recommended actions is to:

- check configured size of connection pool against `processes` `sessions` Oracle startup paramters.
- check Oracles view `v$session`, especially columns `STATUS`, `LAST_CALL_ET`, `SQL_ID`, `PREV_SQL_ID`.
- translate sql_id(prev_sql_id) into sql_text via v$sql.
- if you application has a connection leak, sql_id and pred_sql_id might point you onto a place in your source code, where a connection was used last (i.e. where it was leaked).

Comment: Thanks, the top level exception is `Exception inserting to DB : 
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Unable to get managed connection for jdbc_TestDB; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for jdbc_TestDB)`, there is no `ORA-` mentioned in the StackTrace that I can see.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27512651/836215. Usually Oracle Jdbc driver throws exceptions whose descriptions starts with ORA-<number>. Maybe your wrapper somehow discards these messages, then the investigation will be much harder.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in our code swallowing the exception, so perhaps jBoss is doing this, which I don't have control of. Could this issue be cause by the fact that the session limit and process limit don't match up? The session Max Utilization 1586 is greater that the Processes limit of 1500, the relationship isn't 1:1, but does it make sense to configure a lower limit for Processes? Unfortunately I don't have direct access to or control of the environment where this is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when **max_utilization** gets the **processes** value listener will refuse new connections to database. you can see the errors relates to it in alert log. to solve this in database side you should increase the processes parameter.