# How to find out the java code that has not closed the oracle database connection?

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle11g

I am working on an application that has more than 100 java projects and database connections are established from the projects for running sql.

Now some connections are not closed properly resulting in a connection pool limit reached issue.

To fix the issue the fist step is to find out from which java code connection is not closed properly (in finally block).

**How to find the java code (class name or package name) from where connection is open (i. e connection is not closed)?**

Options Tried:

**Option1:** I tried JDBC connection pool monitoring option in  my weblogic server where JNDI si configured.But its doesn't give any info of the java classes from where the connections is still open.It gives details of the number of open connections and some other details.

**Option2:** Another way i tried is v$session.It also doesn't gives any clue of the java classes/packages that has kept the connection open.

**Option3 :** Eclipse Plugin FindBugs -No issue on open connections in the report.

Please help me how to find the java classes that has kept the connection open?

Comment: findbugs can do that , what makes you think that there is ones which are not closed?

Comment: https://www.yourkit.com

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39347259/836215